# Datepicker Popup (ui.bootstrap.datepickerPopup) Error format date

Tags: angularjs, date, datepicker, angular-ui

I'm trying to use Datepicker Popup (angularjs 1.6.6), from [angular ui](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)
 I've use the example [Plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/k4kiiO3JaGVSs5q432VQ/). All works perfectly but in my project the result is this: [image: REsult in my project]

I've had checked the follogin things:

The files that reference to the .js.

Example:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.5.0.js"></script>
```

My proyect:

```
 <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
 <script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
 <script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
 <script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
```

The style css, maybe here is the problem, but I'm not sure:

Example:

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

My project:

```
@import "bootstrap-sass-official/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap.scss";
```

How can I resolve this? I need to fix the pattern of the date and

I have the module :  "angular-bootstrap": "^2.5.0".

Installing bower install bootstrap, not works

Thanks in advance for your help

P.S: I hope this time the question is in the good format and way of the directives of stackoverflow.